# why ssh connection timed out in vscode?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I  installed git instead of openssl to use Remote-SSH in VSCode.However,after I completed the config document and tried to connect to the remote host.I failed. The error info is showed in the below pic.[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgazs.png)

error info:

```
[11:27:12.631] remote-ssh@0.48.0
[11:27:12.632] win32 x64
[11:27:12.656] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+23321", attempt 1
[11:27:12.659] SSH Resolver called for host: 23321
[11:27:12.659] Setting up SSH remote "23321"
[11:27:12.790] Using commit id "26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0" and quality "stable" for server
[11:27:12.798] Testing ssh with ssh -V
[11:27:13.099] ssh exited with code: 0
[11:27:13.100] Got stderr from ssh: OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
[11:27:13.128] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49485 23321 bash
[11:27:13.132] Install and start server if needed
[11:27:13.151] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[11:27:30.151] Resolver error: Connecting with SSH timed out
[11:27:30.178] ------
```

Comment: have you tried removing the single quotes from the first block? just like you tried on the second block, but on the second block, you don't set the IdentyFile.

Comment: I have tried to connect with or without single quotes and IdentifyFile. But it made no difference. The results are the same: 'Connecting with SSH timed out'

Comment: can you connect to the host using your terminal?

Comment: yes,I can connect to the host using cmd.exe in windows by ssh

Comment: Is "23321" really the hostname? Some software would interpret a digit string as an [IP address](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet.3.html#DESCRIPTION).

Comment: I have the same issue with an Ubuntu client and remote server. Removing my ~/.config/code directory fixes it, but this is clearly not a good option since it removes many other settings as well.

Comment: I can see the welcome message already. Then timeout. *stderr> Authenticated to xxxxx ([IP]:22) using "password".
> Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.2.0 x86_64)*

Answer (score 96):

I had the same problem but the above solutions didn't work with my setup,
but the following setting did work:

```
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
```

I got this solution from [github reported issues and fix](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1721#issuecomment-597783966)

Comment: I can add that this might have something to do with the ControlPersist option being enabled n `~/.ssh/config` since I was not having any issues with this until I turned this flag on

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestions set me up on the right path - I had Fig setup in `~/.ssh/config`, diasbling solved the issue

Comment: A little more information is given [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5925#issuecomment-982887377)

Answer (score 90):

In my case, the problem was caused by a too long authentication process on the server-side.

Solved it by extending the Connect Timeout from 15 to 30 seconds.

Instructions:

1. open your vscode Command Palette (via keyboard shortcut or from the
   View menu).
2. search for the Remote-SSH: Settings.
3. scroll till you find the Connect Timeout.
4. change it to a longer duration than 15 secs.

Comment: I don't understand why vscode has a default ConnectTimeout value in the first place, nor why it is so low (15 seconds). The default should be to use whatever the user has configured SSH to (in general or for that host). I'll add that SSH actually doesn't have an explicit default value either, it uses the TCP default (as it should).

Comment: For me setting it 60 or even 300 does not solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! For me setting it 60 solved the issue

Answer (score 11):

> key F1
> Remote-SSH: Settings
> Connect Timeout: from 15 seconds to 60 seconds solve my connection issue

Comment: For me, setting it 60 - 100 doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

You can try the following approaches:

1. ssh to your remote server. Then run the following commands to clean data folder and bin folder under .vscode-server folder on the server:

- cd ~/.vscode-server
- rm data/* -rf
- rm bin/* -rf

2. If step 1 does not work, ssh to your remote server and delete the entire .vscode-server folder with the following command:

   rm -rf ~/.vscode-server

   Please note that this will also remove the extensions that you installed on the server.
3. Downgrade the version of the remote-SSH extension in vscode. Look up the extension in the vscode interface, right click on that, and you will find the option "Install Another Version ...". Install the previous version of the current one. If it does not work keep downgrading the version.

Comment: This worked for me, but I still had to reboot the box. I think its more to it than just this folder. (note: regular SSH worked fine and in just a few seconds, so its not really a 15second timeout issue in my case)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem before, I solved this by deleting  `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false` inside ~/.config/Code/User/setting.json

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution here in this thread from user oreilm49:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1137

> in vscode settings :
>   search conpty and uncheck it

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue, my problem was solved after changing settings in the json file:

1. I removed `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false` inside `~/.config/Code/User/setting.json`
2. I added `"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true` inside `~/.config/Code/User/setting.json`

It worked for me after so many different trials

Answer (score 3):

This might be a very foolish solution but it actually works for me, so I will write it down in case any other people get into the same problem.
I made modifications to the config file for SSH, then all the trials for connection ran into the error of 'Connecting SSH timed out'. I tried many possible solutions but none of them solved my problem.

Then I just closed the VScode and restarted it. Then everything works.

Answer (score 3):

I had a case of this. I my client (local computer) is a Mac, and I was connecting to Linux host. I just went to the setting "Remote Platform" under Remote.SSH settings, and explicitly told it that I am connecting to a Linux remote. After this, it started to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: damn right bot, that answer was doodoo.

Comment: Go to VSCode preferences, search for `Remote.SSH: Remote Platform`. The top result should be the relevant preference. Click `Add Item`. Under "Item", enter the hostname you're trying to connect to. Under "Value", select "Linux". This worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well before trying all of the above methods, try the nice old method: restart your PC.

I tried all the suggested methods and nothing worked for me, then I just turned off and then on and everything is magically working!

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that on the server I wanted to connect to, the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contained:

```
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Changing that to

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Did solve my ssh connection timeout issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it in settings (I'm using the Remote SSH extension)

```
File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Remote-SSH
```

At the bottom, uncheck `Remote.SSH Use Local Server`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of version missmatch of client and server. After updating both to the same version, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with me was timeout at first. I tried increasing the timeout in settings but then later found the issue was with "tar".

The **vscode-server.tar.gz** (probably a little change in the file name) was not able to install due to **tar not being present in my host**.
So I **installed tar** in the host as "yum install tar"
And then tried reconnecting to the server and **it worked**

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this for a while now... i keep trying to resolve it but unsuccessfully, although i do have a workaround.

My situation is that I regularly run 3 projects together in separate VSCode windows, and one particular project always has this issue lately (especially after a VSCode release restart), even though they are all on the same remote server within my user directory.

The only way i can resolve it (the workaround) is to:

- close VSCode
- go to my user dir in Windows \AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage
- delete the folders (or just the latest timestamp one if you know this is definitely the one for the project with the issue)

Note: i run Windows locally and RHEL remotely.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar to above posts, I just opened command palette (Ctrl+shift+p), searched Remote-SSH settings, and changed the timeout from 15 seconds to something longer

Answer (score 0):

In my case trying from a Mac machine and the server being Linux, I had to add the entry

```json
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "127.0.0.1": "linux"
    },
```

where `127.0.0.1` is the IP address of your remote server

I had tried increasing the timeout to no avail, including restarting vs code

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few different methods in this thread, but none worked for me.

The root cause of my issue was actually due to some hanging nfs mounts located in the `~/.vscode-server` directory. These were caused by an extension I had installed. After uninstalling the extension on the remote server, I was able to delete the files in question and there was no longer an issue with lagginess, which in turn caused timeouts to occur. So if you are experiencing the same issue, check the `~/.vscode-server/bin` directory (where extensions are installed) and see if there are any hanging `nfs` files. If there are, try my method.

Thank you.