# How to troubleshoot Vscode ssh could not establish connection to "hostname"?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a host with Vscode ssh, but I keep getting "could not establish connection to 'hostname'".

I'm confused because it was working perfectly fine and then it stopped working out of the blue.

I did not change the hostname or any config related to ssh in vscode

I can still connect to the host in PuTTY, but I'd like to use vscode

output:

```
[13:55:52.602] Log Level: 2
[13:55:52.604] remote-ssh@0.76.1
[13:55:52.604] win32 x64
[13:55:52.617] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+ug09.cs.ualberta.ca", attempt 1
[13:55:52.617] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[13:55:52.618] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[13:55:52.618] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"ug03.cs.ualberta.ca":"linux","ug09.cs.ualberta.ca":"linux","uf23.cs.ualberta.ca":"linux"}
[13:55:52.618] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[13:55:52.618] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[13:55:52.618] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[13:55:52.618] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[13:55:52.619] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[13:55:52.619] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[13:55:52.619] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[13:55:52.619] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[13:55:52.619] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[13:55:52.619] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[13:55:52.619] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[13:55:52.620] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[13:55:52.620] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[13:55:52.645] SSH Resolver called for host: ug09.cs.ualberta.ca
[13:55:52.646] Setting up SSH remote "ug09.cs.ualberta.ca"
[13:55:52.668] Using commit id "8908a9ca0f221f36507231afb39d2d8d1e182702" and quality "stable" for server
[13:55:52.672] Install and start server if needed
[13:55:52.676] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[13:55:52.729] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[13:55:52.734] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 62422 "ug09.cs.ualberta.ca" bash
[13:55:52.737] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:55:52.985] > 
> 
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:55:52.985] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[13:55:53.000] > 
> 
[13:55:53.256] > abujayya@ug09.cs.ualberta.ca's password: 
[13:55:53.257] Showing password prompt
[13:55:57.151] Got password response
[13:55:57.151] "install" wrote data to terminal: "**********"
[13:55:57.318] > 
> 
[13:55:58.213] > 7037813af524: running
> 
[13:55:58.239] > mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/cshome/abujayya/.vscode-server/bin/8908a9ca0f22
> 1f36507231afb39d2d8d1e182702’: Disk quota exceeded
> Creating the server install dir failed...
> 7037813af524: start
> exitCode==34==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId====
> arch====
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform====
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> 7037813af524: end
> 
[13:55:58.239] Received install output: 
exitCode==34==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId====
arch====
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform====
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====

[13:55:58.240] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[13:55:58.241] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\Mahmoud\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:586041)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Mahmoud\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:584693)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\Mahmoud\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:681846)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\Mahmoud\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:644486
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Mahmoud\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:647831)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Mahmoud\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:645565)
    at async c:\Users\Mahmoud\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.76.1\out\extension.js:1:722872
[13:55:58.245] ------




[13:55:59.490] "install" terminal command done
[13:55:59.491] Install terminal quit with output: 
[13:56:29.738] ConfigFileWatcher: start watching file:///c%3A/Users/Mahmoud/.ssh/config
[13:56:29.738] ConfigFileWatcher: adding save listener
[13:56:29.738] ConfigFileWatcher: adding close listener
[14:00:32.552] Picking SSH host
[14:00:33.624] Selected ug04.cs.ualberta.ca
```

what can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: This may be useful for you :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978826/why-ssh-connection-timed-out-in-vscode

Comment: The server gives you a "Disk quota exceeded" message. Could be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was because the disk quota was exceeded in the remote machine. This was fixed after I freed up some space in the remote machine.

Comment: Thank you! @MahmoudAJ, your answer is helpful! I able to solve the problem of `visual studio code could not establish connection` by free up some space in my remote server.