# git + vscode connect to windows with openssh (remote development)

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, openssh, remote-development

### Setup

I'm connecting to a remote windows machine using OpenSSH. I.e. windows is running the "OpenSSH SSH Server" service. The windows machine has a git repo, e.g. a working directory at `C:\my_git_repo\*` with files I want to edit. How can I get both `git push/pull` *and* vscode's remote development extension to work from my local machine?

I have set up OpenSSH on a windows machine (I'm connecting from linux but I think that's irrelevant): [Setting up OpenSSH for Windows using public key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication) - the `sshd_config` edit was important.

### Git

After this I can `ssh my-window-hostname` and I get a `cmd.exe` prompt. However `git push/pull` does not work:

```
'git-upload-pack' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

To fix that, I changed the OpenSSH shell to use the MINGW64 `bash.exe` that comes with [gitforwindows](https://gitforwindows.org/) as described here: [How do I git clone from a Windows machine over ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834304/how-do-i-git-clone-from-a-windows-machine-over-ssh)

### Vscode

The problem is now that vscode's remote development extension will not connect to my-window-hostname. In the logs I see a successful ssh connection, then the MINGW64 shell version and then `Terminating local server`:

```
[13:25:29.256] stderr> Authenticated to my-window-hostname ([192.168.0.123]:22) using "publickey".
[13:25:30.579] > ready: eaa158feaecd
[13:25:30.703] > MINGW64_NT-10.0-19042 3.3.4-341.x86_64 2022-02-23 17:44 UTC
[13:25:31.729] > local-server-1> Timed out
[13:25:31.737] Local server exit: 0
[13:25:45.414] Terminating local server
```

Someone else has had a similar problem before connecting from macos: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6359
Incidentally, I can `ssh my-window-hostname powershell` just fine. Maybe this is a vscode bug, making an assumption about the shell it gets?

### Both?

It sounds like `git` needs the `bash.exe` shell while `vscode` expects `cmd`. I tried removing the `bash.exe` OpenSSH config and `vscode` started working again. For git I instead set the following in my `~/.ssh/config` (vscode ignores `RemoteCommand` by default):

```
Host my-window-hostname
    RemoteCommand "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
    RequestTTY yes
```

After this I see the MINGW64 bash.exe prompt after a regular `ssh my-window-hostname` however, git is still broken:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This is probably related to git not expecting a TTY/interactive shell, or maybe it's ignoring `RemoteCommand` too.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Since asking here, `enableRemoteCommand` has been implemented. This allows you to use `cmd.exe` as the shell by adding `RemoteCommand cmd.exe` to `.ssh/config`. Better yet, a vscode-only config can be created:

Create `~/.ssh/config_vscode` (e.g. copy from `~/.ssh/config`) and add:

```
Host server-hostname
    RemoteCommand cmd.exe
    RequestTTY yes
```

Set the following User Settings in vscode:

```
{
    ...
    "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": true,
    "remote.SSH.configFile": "/home/username/.ssh/config_vscode",
    "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
}
```

Finally I can now ssh from the command line, add the server as a git remote and run git fetch **and** connect to the server with vscode.

The `useLocalServer` option came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038186/1888983). I blindly added it when I was still seeing a timeout.

I'm still hoping for a more straightforward or easier method. It'd be nice if vscode's remote ssh added a simple shell option.